# Scrapy Middleware Selenium with meta

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

Basically, I have a working version of middleware to pass all requests through selenium and return HtmlResponse, the problem is I also want to have some meta data to be attached to the request which I can access in parse method of spider. For some reason I can't access it in parse method of spider, could you help me please?

middleware.py

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request = request.replace(meta={'test': 'test'})
    self.driver.get(request.url)
    body = self.driver.page_source
    return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

spider.py

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {'meta': response.meta}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the yield of the first function where we Request URL, there is another argument called ***meta*** by which we can pass details from the first function to the second one in a dictionary.

For example, in the first function, we well have:

```
yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_function, meta={'Date Added':date, 'Category':category})
```

In the second function, what we yield is rather this meta  dictionary. This will be like this:

```
yield response.meta
```

What about the details we get from the second function? We should first add them to the dictionary before yield, just as adding to any dictionary, like this:

```
response.meta['Brand'] = brand
response.meta['Model'] = model
response.meta['Price'] = price
```